# AKS Primes algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, primes

A few years ago, it was proven that [PRIMES is in P](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/~manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf). Are there any algorithms implementing [their primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) in Python? I wanted to run some benchmarks with a naive generator and see for myself how fast it is. I'd implement it myself, but I don't understand the paper enough yet to do that.

Comment: AKS is of great theoretical importance but its performance is terrible (Miller-Rabin is much better). There are many primality tests implemented in Python.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you but there is a little mathematical misunderstanding here! Although we haven't formally determined if `P == NP`, but even if `P != NP`, it doesn't follow that `P == Fast`!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Quick answer: no, the AKS test is not the fastest way to test primality. There are much *much* faster primality tests that either assume the (generalized) Riemann hypothesis and/or are randomized. (E.g. [Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_primality_test) is fast and simple to implement.) The real breakthrough of the paper was theoretical, proving that a *deterministic* polynomial-time algorithm exists for testing primality, without assuming the GRH or other unproved conjectures.

That said, if you want to understand and implement it, [Scott Aaronson's short article](http://www.scottaaronson.com/writings/prime.pdf) might help. It doesn't go into all the details, but you can start at page 10 of 12, and it gives enough. :-)
There is also a [list of implementations](http://fatphil.org/maths/AKS/#Implementations) (mostly in C++) here.

Also, for optimization and improvements (by several orders of magnitude), you might want to look at [this report](http://www.southerington.com/souther/projects/aks/RP-3_report.pdf), or (older) [Crandall and Papadopoulos's report](http://developer.apple.com/hardware/ve/pdf/aks3.pdf), or (older still) [Daniel J Bernstein's report](http://cr.yp.to/papers/aks.pdf). All of them have fairly detailed pseudo-code that lends itself well to implementation.

Comment: Update: Another good exposition of the mathematics,by Terence Tao, here: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/the-aks-primality-test/

Comment: The AKS-Test isn't the fastest way, but it is a the first fool-proof test for primes.

Comment: @Progo: More precisely, it's the first test which we can *prove* is fool-proof *and* polynomial-time. There are other tests which we strongly believe *are* actually perfectly fool-proof (e.g. because it is possible to prove them assuming strongly-believed conjectures like the Riemann Hypothesis), and there are also other tests which we can *prove* are perfectly fool-proof, and which almost invariably run fast, but which we can't *prove* are polynomial-time. The breakthrough of the AKS was doing both.

Comment: @Progo, clearly you watched the numberphile video, which is very misleading.  It is not the fastest way, isn't the first fool-proof test, isn't the fastest fool-proof test, etc.  It is deterministic polynomial time, which we didn't have before without assuming the ERH.  We had (and still use today) APR-CL which is effectively polynomial time for any input we will be computing.  We had, and still use, ECPP which is expected polynomial time (but could run slowly due to randomness).  Both are "fool-proof" methods and are much faster.

Answer (score -1):

I simplified using Binomial Expansion,

```
from math import comb
                                
def AKS(n):
    if (n ^ 1 == n + 1):        # check if it's even
        if n == 2:
            return True         
        return False
    for i in range(3,n//2):
        if comb(n,i)%n != 0:    # check if any coefficient isn't divisible by n
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score -6):

Yes, go look at [AKS test for primes](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/AKS_test_for_primes#Python) page on rosettacode.org

```
def expand_x_1(p):
    ex = [1]
    for i in range(p):
        ex.append(ex[-1] * -(p-i) / (i+1))
    return ex[::-1]

def aks_test(p):
    if p < 2: return False
    ex = expand_x_1(p)
    ex[0] += 1
    return not any(mult % p for mult in ex[0:-1])
    print('# p: (x-1)^p for small p')
    for p in range(12):
        print('%3i: %s' % (p, ' '.join('%+i%s' % (e, ('x^%i' % n) if n else '')
                                   for n,e in enumerate(expand_x_1(p)))))

print('\n# small primes using the aks test')
print([p for p in range(101) if aks_test(p)])
```

and the output is:

```
# p: (x-1)^p for small p
  0: +1
  1: -1 +1x^1
  2: +1 -2x^1 +1x^2
  3: -1 +3x^1 -3x^2 +1x^3
  4: +1 -4x^1 +6x^2 -4x^3 +1x^4
  5: -1 +5x^1 -10x^2 +10x^3 -5x^4 +1x^5
  6: +1 -6x^1 +15x^2 -20x^3 +15x^4 -6x^5 +1x^6
  7: -1 +7x^1 -21x^2 +35x^3 -35x^4 +21x^5 -7x^6 +1x^7
  8: +1 -8x^1 +28x^2 -56x^3 +70x^4 -56x^5 +28x^6 -8x^7 +1x^8
  9: -1 +9x^1 -36x^2 +84x^3 -126x^4 +126x^5 -84x^6 +36x^7 -9x^8 +1x^9
 10: +1 -10x^1 +45x^2 -120x^3 +210x^4 -252x^5 +210x^6 -120x^7 +45x^8 -10x^9 +1x^10
 11: -1 +11x^1 -55x^2 +165x^3 -330x^4 +462x^5 -462x^6 +330x^7 -165x^8 +55x^9 -11x^10 +1x^11

# small primes using the aks test
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Comment: This is not the AKS algorithm; this is an **exponential-time** algorithm that implements the elementary idea behind the AKS algorithm with none of the ideas that makes it polynomial-time.