# Is there a Python library to list primes?

Tags: python

Is there a library function that can enumerate the prime numbers (in sequence) in Python?

I found this question [Fastest way to list all primes below N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python) but I'd rather use someone else's reliable library than roll my own. I'd be happy to do `import math; for n in math.primes:`

Comment: The question you link to has a link to the numpy library that has a primes function...

Comment: What is it please? `import numpy` then what? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/search.html?q=prime

Comment: you are always going to have to put some upper limit N ... and for big N value it may take a long time ...

Comment: this may be what your are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567222/simple-prime-generator-in-python  ... see first answer  (which actually links to http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117119/ )

Comment: For the benefit of posterity: @HunterMcMillen's comment of 2012-11-10 was just plain wrong — numpy does _not_ provide a primes function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since asking this question, I wrote a Python wrapper around the C++ library primesieve, which went on to be adopted by the primesieve maintainer. https://github.com/kimwalisch/primesieve-python

Install from PyPi https://pypi.org/project/primesieve/ `pip install primesieve`

```
>>> from primesieve import *

# Generate a list of the primes below 40
>>> generate_primes(40)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37]

# Generate a list of the primes between 100 and 120
>>> generate_primes(100, 120)
[101, 103, 107, 109, 113]

# Generate a list of the first 10 primes
>>> generate_n_primes(10)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]

# Generate a list of the first 10 starting at 1000
>>> generate_n_primes(10, 1000)
[1009, 1013, 1019, 1021, 1031, 1033, 1039, 1049, 1051, 1061]

# Get the 10th prime
>>> nth_prime(10)
29

# Count the primes below 10**9
>>> count_primes(10**9)
50847534
```

Answer (score 47):

[SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/) is another choice. It is a Python library for symbolic mathematics. It provides several functions for prime.

```
isprime(n)              # Test if n is a prime number (True) or not (False).

primerange(a, b)        # Generate a list of all prime numbers in the range [a, b).
randprime(a, b)         # Return a random prime number in the range [a, b).
primepi(n)              # Return the number of prime numbers less than or equal to n.

prime(nth)              # Return the nth prime, with the primes indexed as prime(1) = 2. The nth prime is approximately n*log(n) and can never be larger than 2**n.
prevprime(n, ith=1)     # Return the largest prime smaller than n
nextprime(n)            # Return the ith prime greater than n

sieve.primerange(a, b)  # Generate all prime numbers in the range [a, b), implemented as a dynamically growing sieve of Eratosthenes.
```

Here are some examples.

```
>>> import sympy
>>> 
>>> sympy.isprime(5)
True
>>> list(sympy.primerange(0, 100))
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
>>> sympy.randprime(0, 100)
83
>>> sympy.randprime(0, 100)
41
>>> sympy.prime(3)
5
>>> sympy.prevprime(50)
47
>>> sympy.nextprime(50)
53
>>> list(sympy.sieve.primerange(0, 100))
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Comment: It should be noted here that per `isprime`'s source code, it only checks primes definitively up to 2^64.

Answer (score 19):

The [gmpy2](https://pypi.org/project/gmpy2/) library has a `next_prime()` function. This simple function will create a generator that will provide an infinite supply of primes:

```
import gmpy2

def primes():
    n = 2
    while True:
        yield n
        n = gmpy2.next_prime(n)
```

If you will be searching through primes repeatedly, creating and reusing a table of all primes below a reasonable limit (say 1,000,000) will be faster. Here is another example using gmpy2 and the Sieve of Eratosthenes to create a table of primes. `primes2()` returns primes from the table first and then uses `next_prime()`.

```
import gmpy2

def primes2(table=None):

    def sieve(limit):
        sieve_limit = gmpy2.isqrt(limit) + 1
        limit += 1
        bitmap = gmpy2.xmpz(3)
        bitmap[4 : limit : 2] = -1
        for p in bitmap.iter_clear(3, sieve_limit):
            bitmap[p*p : limit : p+p] = -1
        return bitmap

    table_limit=1000000
    if table is None:
        table = sieve(table_limit)

    for n in table.iter_clear(2, table_limit):
        yield n

    n = table_limit
    while True:
        n = gmpy2.next_prime(n)
        yield n
```

You can adjust table_limit to suit your needs. Larger values will require more memory and increase the startup time for the first invocation of `primes()` but it will be faster for repeated calls.

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of gmpy2.

Comment: The documentation for gmpy2 says: "next_prime(x) returns the next **probable** prime number > x". Emboldened text as per the document. I think that needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 2):

I needed the same thing and decided to create my own to excercise on many things.

Here: [primes.py](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w1w1u1lw145xyac/primes.py?dl=0)

**WARNING:** I tried to bugfix it as much as I could and making checks on everything, but I am still an amateur, so I do NOT guarantee advanced or professional checks and absence of bugs. Use at your own risk.

It will dynamically sieve primes numbers as needed, store them in a compressed binary format and retrieve them from there.

The most useful class is 'primes'. The class itself can be used as a generator, a container, subscripted and sliced.

**WARNING**: be careful iterating on infinite sequences!

```
from primes import primes

for p in primes:  # 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ...
    pass
primes[0]  # 2
primes[4]  # 11
primes[1:6:2] # primes object, generates 3, 7, 13
7 in primes  # True
8 in primes  # False
```

'primes also has useful methods:

```
primes.estimate(1000)  # 7830, real 1000th prime is 7927
primes.check(7)  # True
primes.index_of(11)  # 4 <- primes[4] = 11
primes.count_upto(10) # 4 <- len([2,3,5,7])
primes.sieve(5, 10)  # [5, 7] 
primes.in_range(5, 20, 2)  # primes object, generates 5, 11, 13, 19
primes.factor(12)  # {2:2, 3:1} <- 12 = 2^2 * 3^1
primes.phi(6)  # 6 <- Euler phi function,  number of smaller co-primes
```

And the primes objects are themselves generator, containers, subscriptable and sliceable, but on sublists of primes:

```
primerange1 = primes(1, None, 2)  # generator
for p in primerange1:  # 3, 7, 13, 19, ...
    pass
primerange1[1]  # 7
primerange1[:4:-1]  # generator: 13, 7, 3
2 in primerange1  # False

primerange2 = primes(6, 0, -2)  # generates 13, 7, 3
len(primerange2)  # 3
reversed(primerange2)  # primes object, generates 3, 7, 13
```

The class 'plib' is used to manage the library and its settings.

Answer (score -1):

There is no constant time algorithm to generate the next prime number; this is why most libraries require an upper bound. This is actually a huge problem that needed to be solved for digital cryptography. RSA chooses sufficiently large primes by selecting a random number and testing for primality until it finds a prime.

Given an arbitrary integer `N`, the only way to find the next prime after `N` is to iterate through `N+1` to the unknown prime `P` testing for primality.

Testing for primality is very cheap, and there are python libraries that do so: [AKS Primes algorithm in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347811/aks-primes-algorithm-in-python)

Given a function `test_prime`, than an infinite primes iterator will look something like:

```
class IterPrimes(object):
    def __init__(self,n=1):
        self.n=n

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        n = self.n
        while not test_prime(n):
            n += 1
        self.n = n+1
        return n
```

There are a lot of heuristics you could use to speed up the process. For instance, skip even numbers, or numbers divisible by 2,3,5,7,11,13,etc..