# Prime number generator using gmpy2 producing error

Tags: python, gmpy

I'm trying to test a function in Jupyter Notebooks that uses gmpy2 to produce prime numbers but I'm getting the following output.

```
import gmpy2
def solution(i):
    n = 2
    while True:
        yield n
        n = str(gmpy2.next_prime(n))

for i in solution(1):
    print(i)
    input()
```

```
2

3

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-e0db74781d33> in <module>
      6         n = str(gmpy2.next_prime(n))
      7 
----> 8 for i in solution(1):
      9     print(i)
     10     input()

<ipython-input-14-e0db74781d33> in solution(i)
      4     while True:
      5         yield n
----> 6         n = str(gmpy2.next_prime(n))
      7 
      8 for i in solution(1):

TypeError: next_prime() requires 'mpz' argument
```

Why does the function successfully output the first two numbers in the sequence (2 and 3) but then produce an error? What does `mpz` mean?

Comment: There was an question as same before, I think it will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326673/is-there-a-python-library-to-list-primes

Answer (score 1):

In `n = str(gmpy2.next_prime(n))` you are changing n to string. That's why it yields 2 and 3, where 2 is an integer, 3 is a string, but `gmpy2.next_prime(n)` requires an integer.

Answer (score -2):

```py
import gmpy2
def solution():
    n = 2
    while True:
        yield n
        n = str(gmpy2.next_prime(n))

while True:
    print(solution())
```

try this way

Comment: This doesn't print anything out