# How to write a function to let the output be all prime numbers in range(x,y)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I successfully create a code to determine a prime number,is like this

```
def isprime(num):
  for x in range(2,num):
    if num%x == 0:
      return False
      break
    else:
      return True
dash = "-------------"
print(dash)
while 1:
 no = int(input("Enter number to determine: "))
 print(isprime(no))
```

Then, I decide to write a function so to  let the output be all prime numbers in range(x,y).
So I try,

```
def primein(minNum,maxNum):
  for num in range(minNum,maxNum):    
    for x in range(2,num):              
       if num % x == 0: #DefinitelyNotPrime
         return  True
       else:
         return False
    if True:
      print(num)
       
a = int(input("From: "))
b = int(input("To: "))
print(primein(a,b))
```

And I also try,

```
def primein(minNum,maxNum):
  for num in range(minNum,maxNum):
    fa = 0
    for x in range(2,num):      
       if num % x == 0: #DefinitelyNotPrime
         fa = 0
       else:
         fa = 1
    if fa == 1:
      print(num)
       
a = int(input("From: "))
b = int(input("To: "))
primein(a,b)
```

And it is also not working.
Can someone help me I'm so confused now.

Comment: Can you tell - Does a python library solve your challenge https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326673/is-there-a-python-library-to-list-primes/42440056 ? Are you looking for custom code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of approaches, but the one that is probably most instructive is to *compose* your functions! If you have a function that tells you if a number is prime, *use it*.

```py
def is_prime(num):
    for n in range(2, int(math.sqrt(num))+1):
        if num % n == 0:
            return False
    return True

def find_primes_between(min_, max_):
    primes = []
    for candidate in range(min_, max_+1):
        if is_prime(candidate):
            primes.append(candidate)
    return primes
```

This is *super* inefficient, and indeed it's shockingly accurate to say that the whole study of computer science can be described as "quickly finding prime numbers," but it *works* and it teaches you how to use functions in actual applications.

Comment: Does your code think that 2 is composite?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen eh, yes. Special case it. Consider it a compelling case for unit testing your code :)

Comment: Wait actually no, because `range(2, 1+1)` is empty. 2 returns properly as prime.

Answer (score 0):

you return (True or False) from `primein` as soon as you determine the primeness (or not) of the first number in the range. Thus you never get to the printing (nor to testing a second number).

Do as every programmer does and reuse well-established code, i.e., call your function `isprime` in `primein` to determine primeness. Apart from making this work, you also have a chance to speed up tthe `isprime`function on its own with automatic  benefits for `primein`