# polynomial section of the AKS algorithm in Python

Tags: python, primes

I need a bit of help with the polynomial section of the AKS algorithm.

I have read quite a few descriptions online.
I have got the perfect power test working and I think my get_r() function is correct.
I am not sure how to go about doing this part of the algorithm:

```
For a = 1 to square-root(totient(r) * log(n)):
if (X+a)^n != X^n+a (mod X^r − 1,n), output composite
```

(Also see wikipedia article [AKS primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) for a statement of the [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test#Algorithm).)

Below are links to a program I wrote to implement the miller-rabin test and my (unfinished) aks code.

If someone can explain the maths or give me a bit of pseudocode, I should be okay.
thanks

[aks.py](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pcwq3owcgv1il57/aks.py)
[miller.py](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k3me2xsjn2brwcr/miller.py)

Comment: related: [AKS Primes algorithm in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347811/aks-primes-algorithm-in-python)

Comment: Well, first write something to computer `totient`. Then work out `square_root(totient(r) * log(n)`. Then, `for i in range(1, x)`, check whether the two values above are congruent (fast -- don't work them both out and then reduce!). Which bit of that do you have trouble with?

Comment: Oh, thanks. X is a free variable, so do I test all X from 1 to a?

Comment: sqrt(totient(r) * log(n)) is wrong in that [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test#Algorithm) shows sqrt(totient(r)) * log(n)

Comment: Thanks jwpat7. I didn't spot that.

Comment: @katrielalex I think you have prob. answered this I'll try coding that and see if it works.

Comment: For a fast&simple implementation I'd suggest you to look into the [`flint`](http://www.flintlib.org/) and write a small [C-extension](https://gist.github.com/4383382) to wrap polynomials with modular coefficients and big modulus. There is someone developing python bindings in Cython but until the end of october you couldn't use >2^64 modulus(and I don't know if he added support for this). Using numpy or scipy does not help much, since you'll have to deal with > 2^64 numbers. You may also look at [this](http://yves.gallot.pagesperso-orange.fr/src/aks.html)and try to translate from C++ to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I describe AKS in detail at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com). I'm typing this on my phone so you will have to search for it yourself.

Comment: [AKS blog post on programngpraxis](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/10/02/aks-primality-prover-part-1/)

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Your blog has exactly what I need. I've put the hyperlink in the comment above.