# Why my implementation of aks prime test is slower than my implementation of the naive version?

Tags: python, cryptography, primes

I tried to compare multiple algorithms to find the largest prime number under "i".
But when I tested the implementation, "aks" was slower than my naive implementation.
I was thinking that aks was a better implementation for primality test, did I get this wrong?

```
 def expand_x_1(n): 
    c =1
    for i in range(n//2+1):
        c = c*(n-i)//(i+1)
        yield c
 
def aks(p):
    if p==2:
        return True
 
    for i in expand_x_1(p):
        if i % p:
            return False
    return True

def all_factors(x): # naive version
    i = 2
    s = int(x ** 0.5)
    while i < s:
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
        i += 1
    return True

def find(i, func) :
    while not func(i) :
        i -= 1
    print(i)

%time find(2**16, aks)
%time find(2**16, all_factors)
```

I tried to compare both and obtain:

- for aks

```
65521
CPU times: user 1.7 s, sys: 3.24 ms, total: 1.7 s
Wall time: 1.7 s
```

- for all_factor

```
65521
CPU times: user 81 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 81 µs
Wall time: 83.9 µs
```

Comment: You called them with two separate values.  What makes you think that the two test cases are directly comparable?

Comment: if you use `print(i)` to see how many times it execute `while/for` loops then you will see that naive version has less loops - and because it doesn't use `*` and `//` so it need less time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the input is a prime, `expand_x_1(n)` eventually yields all possible `n//2+1` results, but the loop in `all_factors(n)` goes around only about `sqrt(n)` times. That's a huge difference right there.

But also very much in play:

```py
c = c*(n-i)//(i+1)
```

grows without bound across iterations. Add

```py
            print(c.bit_length())
```

before the `yield`, and you'll see that `find(65521, aks)` is doing arithmetic on integers over 65000 bits wide before it's done. That too is far more expensive than
the 16-bit arithmetic `find(65521, all_factors)` does.

Note: in practice, nobody uses the AKS primality test because even versions that have been massively optimized by world-class mathematicians are slower than alternatives. See [AKS Primes algorithm in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347811/aks-primes-algorithm-in-python) for more on that.